# Debugger.Break() in dll Visual Studio 2010 (c#) and delphi 6 trouble

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Year ago I installed the Visual Studio 2010, after 3 month I intalled Delphi 6 (yep, it's very old) and forgot about Delphi. My OS is Windows XP.

Now, I created dll that runs another program. My dll is as plugin for this program. And I want use debugger.
In my code I use `Debugger.Break()`. Ok, program started, dll started and programm said me: "Do you want to start debugger?". I agreed. And Delphi 6 Debugger started, not VS!
After that I removed Delphi 6, but now than I agree with program offer to use debugger VS debugger doesn't start.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Maybe reinstall the VS will help me but I don't want to do this. Maybe I can change value to Debugger in the Windows, I don't know.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to reset the [just-in-time debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx) to visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find instructions on how to restore these settings on MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)